# Table 'Show More' Reset after Search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that adds a 'Show More' button when there is more than 30 rows in my table. This works for initial page load but disappears after I search/filter the table.

Would it be possible to load/reload the 'Show More' function when/after I have used the search/filter, so it is still useable?

This is the function in question:

```
$(function () {
$table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
    .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
           $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show <span>' +
           numMore + '</span> More</div</tbody></td></tr>');

$('#more').click(function() {
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    if (numShown >= numRows) {
        $('#more').remove();
    }
    if (numRows - numShown < numMore) {
        $('#more span').html(numRows - numShown);
    }
    $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show();
});
});
```

I have tried using a few jQuery listeners which did not give the result I wanted.

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
  $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) === -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();
  });
});

var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index
var numMore = 1; // Increment

var $table = $('#table').find('tbody'); // tbody containing all the rows
var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows

$(function() {
  // Hide rows and add clickable div
  $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
    .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
      $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show <span>' +
      numMore + '</span> More</div</tbody></td></tr>');

  $('#more').click(function() {
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    if (numShown >= numRows) {
      $('#more').remove();
    }
    if (numRows - numShown < numMore) {
      $('#more span').html(numRows - numShown);
    }
    $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="live search">
```

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fk4nkyfp/)

The problem is that when I search, I want the 'Show More' to apply to the search results and not only the initial table.

Comment: Does ajax replace the contents of the table? Not really clear what the problem is without a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Yes - but it also depends on what the user searches/filters for.

Comment: And we would know that from???

Comment: Where in this example do you actually *use* the search/filter function? I don't see where it is applied

Comment: So only search currently visible rows? Still not 100% clear what the issue is based on demo

Comment: @charlietfl No - If you run my example you can see there is two rows and then a 'Show 1 More' button displayed. When I search for 'row:3', for example, I get a result of three rows. What I want is to get a result of one row and a 'Show more' button, not all the rows displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do some changes to the code to make it work as you want:

- Create a new function for creating 'more row'
- Call this function on each search and inside your initial call
- Change the more click to be `on` instead of normal click.

as you can see in the following code:

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
  $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) === -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();


  });
  $('#more').remove();
  addMoreRow();
});

var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index
var numMore = 2; // Increment

var $table = $('#table').find('tbody'); // tbody containing all the rows
var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows

function addMoreRow() {
  $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
    .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
      $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show <span>' +
      numMore + '</span> More</div</tbody></td></tr>');
}

$(function() {
  // Hide rows and add clickable div
  addMoreRow();

  $('table').on('click', '#more', function() {
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    if (numShown >= numRows) {
      $('#more').remove();
    }
    if (numRows - numShown < numMore) {
      $('#more span').html(numRows - numShown);
    }
    $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:7 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:1</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:2</td>
    <td>Row:8 Cell:3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="live search">
```